# How to convert user-input into string

Tags: python

I have the following url as one of my entries:

```
repr(input)
u'www.imdb.com/title/tt1771636/\u200e'
```

If try doing:

```
str(input).lower()
url = str(url).lower()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' 
in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How would I properly encode this to a string and then make it all lowercase?

Comment: Do you have to use `str`? `u'www.imdb.com/title/tt1771636/\u200e'.lower()` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A try/except worked in this case:

```
try:
    url = str(url).lower()
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    url = (url.encode('utf8')).lower()
```